Deleting All Mail Not In Particular Mailboxes
I've organised all emails in my iCloud account that are important to me in particular mailboxes/ folders. I now want to delete all emails that are in the inbox but not in one of these folders. What's the easiest way of doing this?

An email is either in a folder or in the inbox. So all emails in your inbox are not in one of your folders. Thus this is already done. Unless you are taking about macOS Mail app which can have smart folders which are NOT on iCloud
